# Error in seas(., x11 = "") : no output has been generated (R seasonal library isn't working fine)

Tags: r, time-series, x11, decomposition

> library(fpp2) 
> library(seasonal)

> elecequip %>% seas(x11="") -> fit 
> Error in seas(., x11 = "") : no output has been generated

> seas(AirPassengers) 
> Error in seas(AirPassengers) : no output has been generated

(I have reinstalled R as well seasonal library and even clear all objects from work space still the issue/error isn't resolved. I have search a lot how to resolve it but I couldn't find solution. Kindly, help me please ?)

[Click here to view R Script image, where I have updated x13binary package but still error/issue isn't resolved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bGn9.png)

Comment: The seasonal package uses the x13binary package, which may not be working here. Try re-installing x13binary.

Comment: Sir, thank you for response. I have re-installed "x13binary" package but still the issue/error isn't resolve. I have edited my question by adding an R script image to shown what I have done to update and verify "x13binary" package.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in your image says that the `x13binary` package was not installed because you need Rtools installed first. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ on installing Rtools. Then try to install `x13binary` again.

These sorts of questions are probably better handled on http://community.rstudio.com.

Comment: Sir, I have re-installed seasonal and x13binary package again even after installing Rtools properly but still the error/issue doesn't resolve. On your advice I have put the question on R Community. (Thank You)

https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-seas-x11-no-output-has-been-generated-r-seasonal-package-isnt-working-fine/93804

Comment: Sir, You were exactly right there was a issue in x13binary file. I just have to run x13binary manually which resolves the issue.